# Extraction of data from a plot

Tags: python, extract, random-walk

Is it possible to extract data from a plot - for example when having the plot of a random walk, is it possible to quantify the amplitudes of fluctuations etc just because of the plot.

[image: Plot1]

Comment: No, not offhand. There are image-processing modules that would be helpful. You could proabably use the PIL (Python Imaging Library) to extract the curve being plotted, and then determine the y value (the blue pixels) of the curve for each x value. Accuracy would depend on the resolution of the image.

Comment: hmm okay i will try this PIL! thank you for the hint

Comment: For Python 3.x you'll want to get the [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) fork of PIL.